# Can't open Files, Terminal, and Screenshot

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-keyring

After installing new Chrome Remote Desktop browser extension, it somehow harmed my Ubuntu system. Now after reboot I see a warning "the login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer" and I'm not able to open Files, Terminal, Screenshot apps (and maybe more - I haven't tested yet). But I can open Google Chrome, Sublime Text, System Monitor, and IntelliJ IDEA. Though the browser was reset to defaults after the first restart.

Please help me troubleshoot and fix this.

Ubuntu 18.10, Linux 4.18.0-25-generic, x86_64

Comment: UPD. I wanted to do a backup before system reinstall. I can install, but I can't launch a backup program.

Comment: UPD 2. I created a new user and for this user all apps work fine. I just need to customize everything again.

Answer (score -1):

It happened because of broken permissions in home directory. To fix this I used the following commands:

1. Create another user account
2. Log out
3. Log in using the new account
4. Open terminal and navigate to `/home/user1` (where `user1` is the name of the main account)
5. `sudo chown -R user1:user1 ./`
6. `sudo chmod -R 755 ./` (update: DANGER! DON'T DO THIS!!! try to follow the steps skipping #6)
7. Log out
8. Log in using the main account

Comment: sorry, I can't accept your answer because the problem persists after restart